# Which support libraries should I use if my app has minimum skd = 21?

Tags: android, android-support-library

Firstly, let me say that the Android Support Libraries are still a bit intimidating to me. I'm no expert yet. A lot has been written about using them to get api>=21 features on pre-Lollipop devices, but what should I be using if my `minSdkVersion` is 21?

For example, consider `Toolbar`. Is there any reason why I shouldn't use the native version instead of `support.v7.widget.Toolbar`? It should work fine on all post-Lollipop devices. Or, if this is a naive assumption, is there a more recent support library that I should be using?

Comment: The only reason the `v4`, `v7`, etc. libraries exist is because, believe it or not, there are still devices in the world that run early API's and were never updated. If you want your app to reach a larger market, you use the support libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely (though perhaps not right now) it would be good to use the support library version over the system version. The support libraries get features added to it as new Android versions come out.  So, with the support library tools, you'll get features that are available for 21, 22, 23, and beyond. The support libraries will also automatically handle errors if those features are not possible with the certain version of Android (like with the new Permissions apis introduced in 23).

With the system versions, you'll have to check yourself if you're on 21, 22, 23 to use specific methods or functionality.

Now, at the same time, you may not particularly care about these future features.  The `Toolbar` for example is very handy and capable as-is.  If you write something using only the 21 APIs, then they (should) work for future Android versions.

Comment: Another point is that support library behaves in a more consistent fashion than the base libraries.  Particularly around fragments there's some version specific inconsistencies in the base library that are consistent in the support library.

Comment: I see, so the support libraries exist not only to provide newer features to older devices, but also to provide some consistency to developers, regardless of what sdk version is being targeted?

Comment: @moarCoffee  Yes.  And as an Android developer you're going to want as much consistency as you can get.

Comment: Your first comment hadn't loaded before - that answers my question.